# Is there any proof for prophet "mohammed nabi(A) is lay down in qaber for 1500 years"?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, last-day

someone told Me that prophet Mohammed Nabi(A) is lay down in qaber for 1500 years and then the wold ends.Is there any proof for this?up to this how much year after prophets  is dead?

Comment: What is the source of this statement?

Comment: i just heared from my parent and that is why i'm asking for a proof,if it's true the wold ends in this century

Answer (score 2):

This is basically taken from [al-Hawi lil fatawi](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%8A_%D9%84%D9%84%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%89) -a fatwa collection- of Imam Jalal ad-Dyn [as-Suyuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Suyuti) (in the section about fatwa on hadith) where he answered a fatwa saying at the end:

> ولا يمكن أن تكون المدة ألفا وخمسمائة سنة أصلا
> “The period cannot be fifteen hundred years at all.”
> (see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=465&bk_no=130&flag=1) the Question and first replay in Arabic)

Afterwards he quoted statements of other muhaditheen such as Imam at-Tabarni, at-Tirmdihi, ibn abi Hatem, al-Bayhaqi and abu Ja'afar at-Tabari etc. who quoted different ahadith or sayings of sahaba saying that the life time of this life is equal to 7 days of Allah (or 7000 years in some of the quotes) (read also [22:47](http://legacy.quran.com/22/47)):

> ... And indeed, a day with your Lord is like a thousand years of those which you count.

... and that our Prophet () came on the last day (1000 years before the end) (see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=466&bk_no=130&flag=1) and the following pages). Many of these "stories" are among the israeliyat and da'if narrations! (Also take a look in a "selection" from tafsir ibn Kathir of the verse [22:47 in qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2496&Itemid=77) which quote that 1 day of Allah is equal of 1000 years of our count)

Now if we read the Quran we can find verses such as:

> They ask you, [O Muhammad], about the Hour: when is its arrival? Say, "Its knowledge is only with my Lord. None will reveal its time except Him. It lays heavily upon the heavens and the earth. It will not come upon you except unexpectedly." They ask you as if you are familiar with it. Say, "Its knowledge is only with Allah , but most of the people do not know." ([7:187](http://legacy.quran.com/7/187))

or

> People ask you concerning the Hour. Say," Knowledge of it is only with Allah . And what may make you perceive? Perhaps the Hour is near." ([33:63](http://legacy.quran.com/33/63))

or

> They ask you, [O Muhammad], about the Hour: when is its arrival?(42)
> In what [position] are you that you should mention it? (43)
> To your Lord is its finality. (44)
> You are only a warner for those who fear it. (45)
> It will be, on the Day they see it, as though they had not remained [in the world] except for an afternoon or a morning thereof. ([79:42-46](http://legacy.quran.com/79/42-46))

which clearly say that nobody (even not the Prophet) knows when the last day would be except for Allah.

Also read [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/33689).